# Service tomcat8 failed to start by using service tomcat8 start

Tags: linux, tomcat, ubuntu, vagrant, tomcat8

I'm using Vagrant to deploy to Ubuntu Linux and try to start a `tomcat8` service.

Tomcat 8 was installed by `apt-get install tomcat8`.

When using the `service tomcat8 start` command, I got the following error:

> Job for tomcat8.service failed. See "systemctl status tomcat8.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Then I tracked the `systemctl status tomcat8.service`, found that:

---

> ? tomcat8.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
>     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat8)
>     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-03-28 09:44:17 GMT; 5s ago
>     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
>    Process: 884 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/tomcat8 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>    Process: 1312 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tomcat8 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>   Mar 28 09:44:12 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Tomcat....
>   Mar 28 09:44:12 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty tomcat8[1312]: * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat8
>   Mar 28 09:44:17 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty tomcat8[1312]: ...fail!
>   Mar 28 09:44:17 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty systemd[1]: tomcat8.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
>   Mar 28 09:44:17 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Tomcat..
>   Mar 28 09:44:17 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty systemd[1]: Unit tomcat8.service entered failed state.
>   Mar 28 09:44:17 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty systemd[1]: tomcat8.service failed.

I'm unsure of how to proceed to get my Tomcat 8 service running.

Comment: are there any logs in `/var/log/tomcat8/`?

Comment: I found that I couldn't start tomcat8 using `service tomcat8 start` but for some reason it _would_ start using `/etc/init.d/tomcat8 start`.  Not sure that will help you though...

Answer (score 6):

This issue can be caused when the tomcat8 server runs under user tomcat8 and the catalina.out was created by root.

To solve this, delete catalina.out and let tomcat8 recreate it.

Comment: What a Life Saver

Answer (score 2):

This could be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat8/+bug/1586054). Recent versions of Java deprecate the use of endorsed directories and fail if one is specified, but Tomcat8 specifies one even if it doesn't exist. Check the log in `/var/log/tomcat8/` as suggested in the comments to your question to see whether this is indeed the source of your problem. If it is, you can either wait for the bug to be fixed or try the updated catalina.sh file suggested in the linked bug report.

Answer (score 2):

**What I did to solve the issue :**

> Process: 1312 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tomcat8 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

See tomcat's dependencies
`dpkg -s tomcat8-common|grep Depends`

and the system java version
`javar -version`

And try to sort out things with the appropriate java version if things don't match.

---

**If that's not the case, continue :**

Never bad to start with
`sudo apt-get update`

Check eventual running tomcat processes
`ps aux | grep java`

Test the pid you're going to kill
`pgrep -f tomcat`

Targeted action
`sudo pkill -f tomcat`

Start removing by typing `sudo apt-get remove tomcat8-`<kbd>tab</kbd>.
You might find :

> tomcat8-common  tomcat8-user

Complete remove with *( I don't know which of these below is the most appropriate to run )*
`sudo apt-get purge tomcat8` or
`sudo apt-get --auto-remove purge tomcat8` or just
`sudo apt-get remove tomcat8`

You can also
`sudo apt-get autoremove`

Carefully `sudo rm -r` folders like

- /var/lib/tomcat*
- /usr/share/tomcat*
- /etc/tomcat*

Reboot
`sudo systemctl reboot`

When back on track install
`sudo apt-get install tomcat8`

Check how's going
`sudo systemctl status tomcat8.service`
`sudo /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/version.sh`

Better ?

Comment: Unit tomcat.service is masked.

Answer (score 2):

Verify your tomcat8 configuration `file in /etc/default/tomcat8`. See if there are badly configured variables.

For me, this error was caused by the following variables in my configuration file:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xss4m -Xmx2g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

I commented and it worked.

Comment: Hi Isra Taneda, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider adding to your answer so that it becomes a complete answer. As it iscurrently, it is a bit too incomplete For example: what should one look for specificly in config and why would it raise the error? Otherwise, you may use the "comment" function to ask the questioner for more details.