# Cannot install tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I run into this problem over and over again.

I get this message when I try to sudo apt-get install tomcat8

```
Job for tomcat8.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat8.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I was getting this message when I was trying to

```
service tomcat8 start
```

Can anyone help?
So I decided to apt-get purge and apt-get install. And now it doesn't install at all.

What should I do?

Here's the output for

```
systemctl status tomcat8.service
● tomcat8.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
```

Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat8)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-07-12 12:34:58 IST; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3929 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tomcat8 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat8.service
           └─1273 /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat8/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat8 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat8-tomcat8-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

Jul 12 12:34:53 pdave-Inspiron-3521 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Tomcat....
Jul 12 12:34:53 pdave-Inspiron-3521 tomcat8[3929]: * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat8
Jul 12 12:34:58 pdave-Inspiron-3521 tomcat8[3929]: ...fail!
Jul 12 12:34:58 pdave-Inspiron-3521 systemd[1]: tomcat8.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 12 12:34:58 pdave-Inspiron-3521 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Tomcat..
Jul 12 12:34:58 pdave-Inspiron-3521 systemd[1]: tomcat8.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 12 12:34:58 pdave-Inspiron-3521 systemd[1]: tomcat8.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235891/tomcat-8-will-not-start-after-initial-install

Comment: Also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36259907/service-tomcat8-failed-to-start-by-using-service-tomcat8-start